# (Zend) wrapping form element with multiple HtmlTags

Tags: zend-form

I want to do this:

```
<div id="element-wrapper-1">
    <span class="element-wrapper-2">
        <input name="element" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do this using only `addDecorator` methods? I do not want to write my own decorator class or render method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do like this:

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
   'Viewhelper',
   array(
       array('span' => 'HtmlTag'), 
       array('tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'element-wrapper-2')
   ),
   array(
       array('div' => 'HtmlTag'), 
       array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-wrapper-1'))
   )
);
```